# How To Keep Android Studios Logcat From Erasing The Log?

Tags: android, adb, logcat

So everytime I get a crash the Adb logcat will like, completely clear the error I'm currently looking at and display new information. Is there anyway I can get it to retain this information for more than five seconds? I've been taking screen shots of it.

Comment: if you are testing using real device, just unplug it from usb. logs will stay

Comment: @Karan Mer I would then lose the ability to debug realtime though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way for increasing the console output size is to set the idea.cycle.buffer.size value in idea.properties.

Follow this link:
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html

Or Save LogCat To A Text File:

https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-logcat-to-a-text-file

Comment: Hehe, you have to let the timer count down before I can accept it.